# insert list of dictionaries into oracle without unicode symbols using python

Tags: python, json, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert a list of dictionaries into Oracle in Python as a string. Currently I am taking a list that contains several dictionaries and lists then converting it with str() so I can load it into a varchar2 column in oracle. The problem I am having is that the unicode symbols are being loaded into the column which I don't want to happen.

example of uploading one record of one field

```
resultRow = str([{u'key1': [{u'key2': 96, u'key3': u'9999', u'key4': u'blah'}, {u'key2': 4, u'key3': u'9991', u'key4': u'brah'}], u'key5': u'1234', u'key6': u'These Are Words'}])
resultList.append(resultRow)

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('mycredentials')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = 'insert into table1 (fieldname1) values (:1)'
cur.executemany(sql,resultList)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Loaded record in oracle table

```
[{u'key1': [{u'key2': 96, u'key3': u'9999', u'key4': u'blah'}, {u'key2': 4, u'key3': u'9991', u'key4': u'brah'}], u'key5': u'1234', u'key6': u'These Are Words'}]
```

I have been able to traverse the list and dictionaries, but it is a lot of extra processing when I really just want to dump the results.

```
'; '.join('KEY5:'+d['key5']+', '+'KEY6:'+d['key5']+', '+'KEY1:('+', '.join('KEY4:'+x['key4']+', '+'KEY3:'+x['key3']+', '+'KEY2:'+str(x['key2']) for x in d['key1'])+')' for d in resultList)
```

Loaded record in oracle table

```
KEY5:1234, KEY6:These Are Words, KEY1:(KEY4:blah, KEY3:9999, KEY2:96, KEY4:brah, KEY3:9991, KEY2:4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have json in the tags why not use it:

```
import json

resultList = []
resultRow = json.dumps([{u'key1': [{u'key2': 96, u'key3': u'9999', u'key4': u'blah'}, {u'key2': 4, u'key3': u'9991', u'key4': u'brah'}], u'key5': u'1234', u'key6': u'These Are Words'}])
resultList.append(resultRow)

#insert

#fetch

resultRow = json.loads(row.col #or however you get the data from the oracle driver)
```